# Applying anchor tag to each element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have grabbed this data from a database (`profile.designations`) 
which returns a string:

```
"AEA, CAP, AAA"
```

I know that to turn that into an array (to work with it further) I have to use      `profile.designations.split(" ")` which will return:

```
["AEA", "CAP", "AAA"]
```

But now I want to apply an anchor tag to each element so that ultimate the DOM reads each designation nested in an anchor tag. How do I append that to the array I got?

Answer (score 3):

Actually if the text returned is in the format `'foo, bar, baz'` you should split as follows:

```
var items = 'foo, bar, baz'.split(', '); // => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Secondly, if you want to "wrap in an anchor tag" you will have to be more specific. If you want strings you can do the following:

```
items.map(function(item) { return '<a>' + item + '</a>' });
```

However if you want actual DOM elements, do the following:

```
items.map(function(item) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.innerText = item;
  return a;
});
```

**Edit**: Also, if you want to just append to page (let's say, body):

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.innerText = item;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
});
```

Comment: For items.map(function(item) { return '<a>' + item + '</a>' });  how would I then return the elements so that the newly anchored elements are no longer in an array?

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you don't want them in an array how do you want them? Do you want to append them to a page?

Comment: After doing items.map(function(item) { return '<a>' + item + '</a>' }) so  that each element is nested in an anchor tag, I want these links to now be shown on the page. They are still in an array. I'm assuming the next step is to get them out of the array so that the links are shown on the page?

Comment: Yes, or instead of using map you can do it in a `forEach` loop since you aren't making a new array.

Comment: But forEach is still dealing with an array and will return the array. I want to have the element out of the array as an end result?

Comment: @sk_255 edited post to show you what I mean.